# ", and is available for download" or ", and is available to download"?

Tags: grammar

what is mistake? i try but all version sound to me as incorrect...help

```
Geostorm is a free-to-play, puzzle and action game developed by Sticky 
Studios, and is available for download on both iOS and Android devices.
```

mybe this is correct?

```
Geostorm is a free-to-play, puzzle and action game developed by Sticky 
Studios, and is available to download on both iOS and Android devices.
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"available to download" and "available for download" are both correct.

There is no practical difference between them.

It doesn't even make a different in terms of style but is another example of English having many similar options for expressing the same thing.

"Available for download" is currently the most widely used [per ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=available+to+download%2Cavailable+for+download%2Cavailable+for+downloading&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavailable%20to%20download%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cavailable%20for%20download%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cavailable%20for%20downloading%3B%2Cc0)